# Unsupervised ranking of samples

Tags: unsupervised-learning, ranking

Say I have a dataset of n samples. I want to maximize every feature’s value. I’m not sure if feature 1 is more important than feature 2, etc. Are there any methods of ranking my samples out there? If I knew the importance (weight) of each feature, I would simply put all the features on the same scale, calculate the weighted mean of the features for that sample, then list the samples from highest weighted mean to lowest, but I don’t know the weights.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not with the information you provide, here.

With the given information, it is not possible for two different rankings to determine which one would be better. Without this possibility, there is nothing to optimize for and from an algorithmic point any answer is as good (there is the exception of the ranking of samples, where one sample is larger than the other in every feature: in this case the larger sample should be ranked first)

To allow for a meaningful ranking, one would need some more information, e.g.:

- domain knowledge of the feature importance
- a possible downstream task (best with objective)
- a goodness measure for a ranking